# How do you create a cookie in JavaScript without JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

So what I'm saying is that can you create a cookie without using JQuery and only JavaScript.
Do you have an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have these simple function to do that

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

**Now, calling functions**

```
createCookie('ppkcookie','testcookie',7);

var x = readCookie('ppkcookie')
```

Answer (score 1):

[Create cookies with javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

JavaScript can create, read, and delete cookies with the document.cookie property.

With JavaScript, a cookie can be created like this:

```
document.cookie = "username=John Doe";
```

You can also add an expiry date (in UTC time). By default, the cookie is deleted when the browser is closed:

```
document.cookie="username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC";
```

With a path parameter, you can tell the browser what path the cookie belongs to. By default, the cookie belongs to the current page.

```
document.cookie="username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
```

All together code:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user = getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
    } else {
        user = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
        if (user != "" && user != null) {
            setCookie("username", user, 365);
        }
    }
}
```